# Third param Java8 reduce on string attribute in Object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, reduce

The question is quite simple for Stream Guru:

I have this:

```
    List<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<>();
    beans.add(new MyBean("tutu"));
    beans.add(new MyBean("toto"));
    beans.add(new MyBean("titi"));
```

Comparing:

```
 StringBuilder reduced
            = beans.parallelStream()
                    .map(MyBean::getName)
                    .reduce(new StringBuilder(), (builder, name) -> {
                        if (builder.length() > 0) {
                            builder.append(", ");
                        }

                        builder.append(name);
                        return builder;
                    }, (left, right) -> left.append(right));
```

and

```
 StringBuilder reduced
            = beans.parallelStream()
                    .map(MyBean::getName)
                    .reduce(new StringBuilder(), (builder, name) -> {
                        if (builder.length() > 0) {
                            builder.append(", ");
                        }

                        builder.append(name);
                        return builder;
                    }/* WITHOUT THIRD PARAM*/);
```

Why, the second solution doesnt compile... the Third parameter is for the parrallel stream...

Could you explain why I'm not able to compile the second code section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is because this overload of [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

takes two arguments, the second being a [`BinaryOperator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) which basically represents an operation upon ***two operands of the same type*** producing a result of the same type as the operands. This contract is not obeyed in your second code snippet as your `map` operation returns a `Stream<String>` whereas the *identity* is of type `StringBuilder`. To prevent the compiler error, simply make both the *identity* value as well as the operands of the *accumulator* function be the same types i.e:

```
StringBuilder reduced
                = beans.stream()
                .map(b -> new StringBuilder(b.getName()))
                .reduce(new StringBuilder(), (builder, name) -> {
                    if (builder.length() > 0) {
                        builder.append(", ");
                    }

                    builder.append(name);
                    return builder;
                }/* WITHOUT THIRD PARAM*/);
```

on the other hand this overload of [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

accepts a [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) as the second argument which can consume ***two different types of objects*** hence why your first code snippet works without a compiler error.

Lastly, don't forget to change the `beans.parallelStream()` to `beans.stream()` as shown within the solution above.

as an aside, note that when performing operations in parallel, the *accumulator*, as well as the *combiner*, **must** be [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity), [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) and [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness). If this is not taken into account, your result will be *nondeterministic* arbitrary result.

**edit:**

as mentioned by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger):

> Modifying incoming parameters in a reduction function is broken by
>   definition, even if it happens to produce the intended outcome in a
>   sequential context. It also violates the contract of the first
>   parameter, as the modified `StringBuilder` is not an identity value
>   anymore. You can use Reduction with immutable values, as
>   `.map(MyBean::getName).reduce((a,b) -> a + ", " + b).orElse("");` or use
>   Mutable Reduction like
>   `.map(MyBean::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));`

Comment: It’s more than a side note. Modifying incoming parameters in a reduction function is broken by definition, even if it happens to produce the intended outcome in a sequential context. It also violates the contract of the first parameter, as the modified `StringBuilder` is not an identity value anymore. You can use Reduction with immutable values, as `.map(MyBean::getName).reduce((a,b) -> a + ", " + b).orElse("")` or use Mutable Reduction like `.map(MyBean::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`…

Comment: @Holger true, that makes complete sense. I'll use your suggestion within the post. very much appreciated.